# Upload Files to FTP location from S3 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

How do I Upload files of a specific pattern from an S3 location to FTP location in Python using ftplib and boto3??

I was able to upload files from local as below but not from S3. Can someone suggest a way to achieve this??

```
# Upload Files 
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import glob

host    = 'ftp.xyz.com'
uname   = 'user_name'
pwd     = 'My_Password'
sdir    = 'location'
sfrmt   = 'sample*'

ftps = FTP_TLS(host)
ftps.login(user = uname, passwd = pwd)

ftps.cwd(sdir) 

files =  glob.glob(sfrmt)
files
['sample1.csv', 'sample2.csv', 'sample3.csv']
for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as fu:
            ftps.storbinary('STOR ' + f, fu)

'226 Transfer complete.'
'226 Transfer complete.'
'226 Transfer complete.'
```

Comment: You cannot copy directory between FTP and S3. You should download the desired file(s) from S3, then upload via FTP.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Thanks for the response. I think there's a way to download files from FTP to s3 directly (Something like below). So I thought there should be a way to do upload to FTP from S3.
https://github.com/kirankumbhar/File-Transfer-FTP-to-S3-Python/blob/master/ftp_to_s3.py

Comment: That code is still downloading and uploading, but it looks like it might simply be downloading 'chunks' into memory and then uploading. The benefit is that it doesn't hit the disk. The downside is that it is more complex. Regardless, it is still downloading and uploading, rather than transferring directly.

Comment: You might want to use a utility like [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) to do the transfer. It will probably let you drag & drop between S3 and FTP, and it will do all the hard work for you.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah it’s doing chunks and I agree it’s a complex approach and I’ve seen some scenarios of loosing data too. Cool thanks for clarifying the there’s no direct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 
import os    
import s3fs
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

ftp = FTP_TLS("xxxxxxx.com")
ftp.login(user = "UserName", passwd ="Password")
ftp.cwd("Ftp Location")

s3_path = 's3://myBucket/Prefix/files'
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False) 
obj_lst = fs.ls(s3_path)
upload_lst = [i for i in obj_lst if "FileFormat" in i] # Upload files of this pattern

for file in upload_lst:
    with fs.open(file, 'r') as fu:
            ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(file), fu)
```